# How do I pass a dynamically created list to the controller to save into the database?

Tags: php, zend-framework, concrete5

I am working in Concrete5 and am new to the MVC concept. I have a some jquery that creates an unordered list from a textbox in my view. If your familiar with Concrete5 this is the view for the block I am adding the list to. It is basically a list of features for a product. This view needs to save the list to the database base file. Usually this is done pretty simply using a variable that the information gets saved to (aka this is how everything else in the view is saved). The problem I am having is I do not know how to use the controller to pass the unordered list from the view to the controller to the database so that it saves it. Any help and sample code would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure I need to write a php function in my controller to get the list but I am not sure what the code would be.

auto.js

```
$("#addList").click(function() {
    var text = $("#inputList").val() + '<button>x</button>';
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.featureList')
        };
});
$('ul').on('click','button', function(el){
    $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

add/edit.php

```
<div class="ccm-block-field-group">
<h2><?php echo t('Features') ?></h2>
```

Right now 'features' is the name of the field in my database file db.xml
The area featureList is where the list get generated into. I know it needs to be changed around a bit to work, just not sure.

```
<?php echo $form->textarea('features', $features, array());?>
<input type="test" id="inputList" />
<button type="button" id="addList">Add</button> 
<ul class="featureList"></ul>
</div>
```

view.php

```
echo "<h2>{$proName}</h2>";
echo "{$description}";
echo "<h3>{$features}</h3>";
echo "<h2>{$price}</h2>";
echo "<p>{$priceInfo}</p>";
```

db.xml

```
<field name="features" type="X2"></field>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for what you already have? It'd probably be easier if I look at it and point out what you need to change to support the list.

Comment: there are a few files. I am not sure what sections of each you would need to look at. Maybe if you can give some advice on how the pages are supposed to interact I will have a better understanding and can post the appropriate sections of code. There is my controller, view, js and add/edit php pages. The add/edit pages update the view. This is where my dynamically generated list is. I need it to store all the li values and save it to the database so that when view.php is loaded it will display the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed around the auto.js file so it is as follows. Seems to work fine.

```
var listItemCounter = 0;
$("#addList").click(function() {
    listItemCounter++;
    var text = $("#inputList").val(); //assign a unique id number to this button, so it knows which hidden field to remove when clicked
    var buttonDataId = text + '<button data-id="' + listItemCounter + '">x</button>';
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: buttonDataId}).appendTo('ul.featureList');
        $('<input type="hidden" name="features[]" value="' + text + '" data-id="' + listItemCounter + '" />').insertAfter('ul.featureList');
        };
});
$('ul').on('click','button', function(el){
    $('input[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').remove();//remove the hidden field so it does not get POSTed when user saves
    $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

I left the view the same as what Jordan Lev put. (Thanks!)
Then I changed the controller.php to

`public function save($args) {
    $args['features'] = implode("\n", $args['features']);//combine all feature items into one string, separated by "newline" characters
    parent::save($args);
}`

If anyone sees any problems or a better way to put my code please let me know!
My new problem now is once it is saved, if I go to edit the list, it wipes out my past entries and saves the new one. If anyone knows the function I would have to write to  show the current list and add to it when editing that would be great. Please give some example code.

Comment: Basically list is saved and shows let say 4 features. When I am in edit mode and need to edit the block, how would I get that to update to show the current list (the 4 features) so I can either add more features or delete them?

Answer (score 1):

With concrete5 blocks, there are two different situations you could be in:

1. admin user is editing the block (or adding a new block), and you want to save this data to the database.
2. public user is viewing the block, but the block view itself has a form (for example, a contact form block) and you want to do something when the public form is submitted (for example, send a notification email to an admin that someone has filled out the form, or store the submission in a database for future review).

If you're talking about situation #1, you need to put some custom code in the controller's `save()` method. If you're talking about situation #2, you need to create your own action method in the controller, AND you need to actually have a `<form>` in the view.php file.

UPDATE: Based on the sample code you added to your question, here is the solution:
The only way your data can get back to the server is via a form POST. `<li>` elements are not form fields, and hence the data in them doesn't get POST'ed with the form. So when you add the new `<li>` element to the page, you should *also* add a hidden form field, like so:

```
    var listItemCounter = 0;
$("#addList").click(function() {
        listItemCounter++;
    var text = $("#inputList").val() + '<button data-id="' + listItemCounter + '">x</button>'; //assign a unique id number to this button, so it knows which hidden field to remove when clicked
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.featureList');
        $('<input type="hidden" name="features[]" value="' + text + '" data-id="' + listItemCounter + '" />').insertAfter('ul.featureList');
    };
});
$('ul').on('click','button', function(el){
        $('input[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').remove(); //remove the hidden field so it does not get POSTed when user saves
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Now, in your block's controller.php file, you will want to add a `save()` method that will take all of the data from those hidden fields, combine them and put them into the "features" field that you declared in your db.xml file:

```
public function save($args) {
    $args['features'] = implode("\n", $args['features']); //combine all feature items into one string, separated by "newline" characters
    parent::save($args);
}
```

Finally, in your view.php file, you can convert the list of features (which was saved to the database as one string, with each item separated by a "newline" character) like so:

```
<?php echo nl2br($features); ?>
```

Or if you want to output it as separate list items, you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
$features = explode("\n", $features);
foreach ($features as $feature) {
    echo '<li>' . $feature . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is in situation 1. I am creating a product block and would like to be able to populate a features list dynamically inside the add/edit page. I use an auto.js file to create <li> tags with a value form an input box. These <li> tags and values get displayed underneath. I need to save each <li> + val + </li> so that it will be displayed in the final view.php (both user and admin see). I will post my auto.js and my add/edit.php

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account your new details. Hope it helps!

Comment: in the auto.js file, the button is duplicating because it is included in var text. So the output of the hidden field is as follows...                '<input type="hidden" name="features[]" value="death<button data-id=" 1"> "x" />"'

Comment: also there is already a function save($data). How would I integrate the $args? Combine $data into the $args?

Comment: Add your help has been absolutely amazing. Thank you a million. Saving newbie lives over here.

Comment: As of right now I get this error message.                Warning: Missing argument 2 for ProductInformationBlockController::save(), called in /var/www/vhosts/colorado-remodeling.com/httpdocs/concrete/core/models/block.php on line 411 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/colorado-remodeling.com/httpdocs/blocks/product_information/controller.php on line 26 Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/vhosts/colorado-remodeling.com/httpdocs/blocks/product_information/controller.php on line 27 {"aID":"105","arHandle":"Main","cID":"141","error":false,"bID":"190"}

Comment: so if I just take out the whole function save($data) then it saves but I still need to straighten out the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Jordan Lev. If I get this product information block solid I am planning to unleash it to the Concrete5 community for free.

Answer (score 0):

You dont pass stuff from the view to the controller. The controller is executed BEFORE the view, so you only pass from controller to view.

Try accessing the stuff you pass from jquery to your application using

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('yourParametersName');
```

inside the controller.

Lucian

Comment: Also if you look at my comment under my question, maybe you could give me a few pointers real quick. I am new to this so any help is appreciated. Thanks.