# In Concrete5 how do I update my block edit view to show the current values saved in the database?

Tags: php, jquery, concrete5, dynamic-list

I have code that dynamically creates a product features list and puts all the values together into one string seperated by newline characters and gets saved to the database. When this string is passed to the view I output as an unordered list. When I go to edit the block it does not show what is already in the list, so I have to retype all the features everytime I need to edit my block, even if it's not the feature list (I have some titles and other textareas). If I put the php variable into my edit page it will show me what has been saved but I would need it to be instantly added to the list and not showing separate. I basically need it to "auto appendTo" my `<ul>`. Here is my code...

controller function to save the list in controller.php

```
public function save($args) {
        $args['features'] = implode("\n", $args['features']);//combine all feature items into one string, separated by "newline" characters
        parent::save($args);
    }
```

my edit.php - this will show it in a list. If I just put `echo $features` it outputs the string.

```
echo '<div class="ccm-block-field-group">';
echo '<h2>' . t('Features') . '</h2>';
echo '<input type="text" id="inputList" />';
echo '<button type="button" id="addList">Add</button>';
echo $features = explode("\n", $features);
        foreach ($features as $feature) {
            echo '<li class="currentFeatures">' . $feature . '</li>';
        };

echo '<ul class="featureList">';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

my auto.js - handles creation of the list

```
var listItemCounter = 0;
    $("#addList").click(function() {
        listItemCounter++;
        var text = $("#inputList").val(); //assign a unique id number to this button, so it knows which hidden field to remove when clicked
        var buttonDataId = text + '<button data-id="' + listItemCounter + '">x</button>';
        if(text.length){
            $('<li />', {html: buttonDataId}).appendTo('ul.featureList');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="features[]" value="' + text + '" data-id="' + listItemCounter + '" />').insertAfter('ul.featureList');
            };
    });
    $('ul').on('click','button', function(el){
        $('input[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').remove();//remove the hidden field so it does not get POSTed when user saves
        $(this).parent().remove()
    });
```

and finally part of my db.xml

```
<field name="features" type="X2"></field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something similar to what I explained for the "view" in your other question ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14968046/477513 ).

You want to change the list from a string to an array (via `explode("\n", $features)`), then run your javascript on each of those features. Since this is basically the same javascript that you'd do when someone adds a new item via the textbox, you will want to move all that code into a function and call the function in both situations (otherwise you will be copying and pasting the same code, which violates the "Don't Repeat Yourself" rule and inevitably leads to bugs in the future). So your auto.js code could look something like this:

```
var listItemCounter = 0;

function addItem(text) {
    if (text.length) {
        listItemCounter++;
        var itemHtml = '<li data-id="' + listItemCounter + '">'
                     + text
                     + '<button data-id="' + listItemCounter + '">x</button>'
                     + '</li>';
        var inputHtml = '<input type="hidden" name="features[]" value="' + text + '" data-id="' + listItemCounter + '" />';
        $('ul.featureList').append(itemHtml);
        $('ul.featureList').after(inputHtml);
    }
}

function removeItem(id) {
    $('input[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();
    $('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();
}

$("#addList").click(function() {
    additem($("#inputList").val());
});

$('ul').on('click','button', function(el) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    removeItem(id);
});
```

Then in your edit.php file, add this code to output the saved data and call the addItem function on each one:

```
<?php
//populate existing data when edit dialog is first opened
$featuresPHPArray = explode("\n", $features);
$featuresJSArray = Loader::helper('json')->encode($featuresPHPArray);
?>
<script>
var savedItems = <?php echo $featuresJSArray; ?>;
$.each(savedItems, function() {
    addItem(this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: its not working. I get nothing. Do I have to put anything new in my edit.php? Also is it ok to put php code into a .js file? Just was wondering.

Comment: I really really appreciate all your help. I will let you know when this block is done and put it on the C5 community for free.

Comment: Also I don't exactly need it as a list before it gets run through the jQuery, just when it outputs to the list. I just need to get the values (using explode) and populate them as `<li>` in the `ul.feature List`

Comment: you're totally right -- cannot run php in a js file. Sorry about that, I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: awesome!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it updates and places it into the list of features!!!!!!!!!!!! There is one small problem though... it won't add new items to the list, could it be that `function addItem(text)` has text as the parameter and the `#inputList` is getting the val?

Comment: you are saving my hair from falling out!

Comment: The addList .click funtion isn't working. It won't even alert.

Comment: Fixed it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Inside the `$("#addList").click(function(){})` the `addItem($("#inputList").val());` had a lowercase **i** instead of an upercase one.

Comment: glad you got it fixed! How about accepting my answer so I get a little rep from this?